# Symbols not loaded for java.exe

Tags: c++, swig, debug-symbols

Im sure this question is probably worded poorly, so please ask me questions and Ill respond promptly.

Im compiling some code in debug and putting the resulting .dll where my web server starts from.
When I start the web server, a java.exe process gets started.
Im trying to hit a breakpoint in my code by attaching to this java process through Visual Studio,
but Im getting the "no symbols have been loaded for this document" problem.

I think I need the .pdb symbol file for this code to be associated with the java process in order to debug, but understandably they are not compatible. 
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The path of the pdb file is stored in the DLL so as long as it's in the original location the debugger should find it.

Comment: Captain Oblivious, you are correct. Thanks. Turned out my problem was a result of something else.